# How to overcome limit of linking multiple object files in make file

Tags: makefile, nmake

I am new to makefile concept. So please can anyone give me example to overcome the problem of linking too many make files. Because I am getting error "fatal error U1095:" in my make file.

Comment: post a little bit more detail (toolchain, make version, system shell) and perhaps the relevant code from the make file.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming windows (since on windows, [the command line is limited to 128 characters <sup>(?! really - sic?!)</sup>)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/23bz2yst%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

I suggest you use `@response` files for LINK.EXE and or CL.exe etc.

```
LINK.EXE @response.tmp
```

You can store all commandline parameters in the text file without any limit.

**Update** MSDN calls them **[Command Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9xch38h8%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)**

Comment: thanks for giving quick response. I have one question. Where to put this resonse.tmp file?

Comment: @Ganeshkumar: whereever you want (as long as you have permissions there and don't risk creating a mess. Usually under %TMP% ). I think nmake may have facilities for managing temporary files. I don't know nmake enough to tell you more